# How to use ^ in regexp?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like start string with `[a-z]` and next symbols can be `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, so I did:

```
^[a-z]*\S
```

But this didn't work.

Without `^` work good, but allow strings to start with capital letters and numbers.

Examples:

```
aaaa - should be ok
2aa  - should be false
a - ok
1 - false
Asdf - false
aDS3r -  ok
ssdfg2 - ok
```

Comment: Move the `*` after `\S` most likely.

Comment: Do you understand what `^` does?

Comment: \S is not the same as [a-zA-Z0-9].  \S means "no whitespace", but that can include far more than letters and numerical digits... at least in the various implementations I am aware of.  This comment also goes for the answers who ignored this detail.

Comment: @CPerkins yup I updated the answer to take that in consideration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead:

```
^[a-z]\w*
```

**Snippet below**

```js
array = ["aaaa", "2aa", "a", "1", "Asdf", "aDS3r", "ssdfg2" ];
array = array.map(function(x) {
  return x.replace(/^[a-z]\w*/g, " TRUE ")
});
console.log(array)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like You should change `*` to `+` to catch at least one symbol from `[a-z]`, and \S should be is not required

```
^[a-z]+\S*
```